# Interface Builder not working with xib, storyboard, assets

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib

Xib, storyboard, asset files are not shown by Interface Builder in my Xcode. They all are opened as text files.

When I right click and choose Open As..., there is only a grayed out None option.

When I open the file via Finder and choose Xcode as the application, Interface Builder works.

I upgraded my Xcode version from 12 to the latest (13.3.1), rebooted my Mac, cleaned build folder, but still it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out that this happens when "Enable Code Review" option is toggled on. Xcode started working as expected when I disabled it.

[image]